# prove the following theorem by using the hint

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

prove the following,

Let (x$_n$) be a bounded, increasing sequence of real numbers. That is, x$_1$ ≤ x$_2$ ≤ x$_3$ ≤··· . Then (x$_n$) converges to some real number c.

[Hint: Let c = sup{x$_n$|n = 1,2,3,...}. To show that lim n→∞ x$_n$ = c, let ε> 0. Note that c−ε is not an upper bound. You take it from here!]

how the hint can be used to prove the question?

Comment: "Metahint": what does mean to say that $c-\varepsilon$ is not an upper bound of $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$?

Comment: You know the sequence is bounded; so it has some upper bound.  The hint says to find the <i>least</i> possible upper bound $c$, and show that the sequence must converge to it, by looking at what happens when you try to use a smaller number as an upper bound for the sequence.  

Always keep in mind that the sequence is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $c$ is the least upper bound of $\{x_n\}$, so $c-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound. That means there exists some $N$ such that $x_N > c-\epsilon$. Note that this can be done for any $\epsilon>0$. A little more work will give you the conclusion $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = c$. (You will need to use the fact that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is increasing.)